# Blanket hreflang or lang attribute for single language website

Tags: html, lang, hreflang

My marketing team is on me to fix Site Audit errors reported by Semrush and Ahrefs.

The error is: "218 pages have no hreflang and lang attributes"

This is a single language site - all in US English.  I realize I can go into 218 pages and change < html > to < html lang="en" >.  However, my full site is more than 2000 pages so I think the 218 count is just that site audit stopped there.

I'd like to just put a default in the page header for all pages.  I see the syntax for hreflang alternate, but I don't think it's right for a single language site.

Is there a way for me to add a blanket default that makes semrush site audit know that all my pages are lang="en" ?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a common header and all that pages are part of the same domain, you can use

`<link rel="alternate" hreflang="x-default" href="https://www.yourURL.com<?php echo $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]; ?>" />`
 in the head and the "x-default" handles the language for you.
Here is a url that explains better the usage of 'x-default':
https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2013/04/x-default-hreflang-for-international-pages.html

I hope it helps.

Comment: This worked beautifully.  It resolved 177 of the 218 errors, and I think the remaining 30 are just a different header text.

Comment: I'm glad it was useful. And yeah, it probably is because of a different header.